# Randomise Data In Databate

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, post

JACKPOT PAGE:

```
Username: <input type="text"     name="user_name">

<select name="number1">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="100">1</option>
<option value="200">2</option>
<option value="300">3</option>
<option value="400">4</option>
<option value="500">5</option>
<option value="600">6</option>
<option value="700">7</option>
<option value="800">8</option>
<option value="900">9</option>
</select>

<select name="number2">
<option value="00">0</option>
<option value="10">1</option>
<option value="20">2</option>
<option value="30">3</option>
<option value="40">4</option>
<option value="50">5</option>
<option value="60">6</option>
<option value="70">7</option>
<option value="80">8</option>
<option value="90">9</option>
</select>

<select name="number3">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>



<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

RESULT PAGE:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime();

define('DB_NAME', 'test');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) 
{
    die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) 
{
    die('Can\'t use '.DB_NAME.': '.mysql_error());
}

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM config") or die(mysql_error());  
$number1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number1']);
$number2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number2']);
$number3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number3']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
    if($info['jackpot_code'] == ($_POST['number1'] + $_POST['number2'] + $_POST['number3']))
    {
        echo 'CORRECT!';
    }   
    else if(($info['jackpot_code'] - ($_POST['number1'] + $_POST['number2'] + $_POST['number3'])) <= 30 && ($info['jackpot_code'] - ($_POST['number1'] + $_POST['number2'] + $_POST['number3'])) >= 0 or ($info['jackpot_code'] - ($_POST['number1'] + $_POST['number2'] + $_POST['number3'])) >= -30 && ($info['jackpot_code'] - ($_POST['number1'] + $_POST['number2'] + $_POST['number3'])) <= 0){
        $code = $_POST['number1'] + $_POST['number2'] + $_POST['number3'];
        echo "Guessed code: $code<br>";
        die('The code u guessed is at the range of +/- 30 to jackpot.');
    } else
    {
        die('CODE FALSE!');
    }
}

$number = $_POST['number1'] + $_POST['number2'] + $_POST['number3'];

echo "<br>Guessed code: $number";

$sql = "INSERT INTO jackpot_log (username, code, time) VALUES ('".$username."','".$number."','".$date->getTimestamp()."')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) 
{
    die('Error: '. mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
```

This is my code and it fully work. The thing is: I want to change my "jackpot_code" from my "config" table at my Database. Is there a way to randomise this table and generate a new 3 digit code after every successful attemp.

Here is my Database:
All i need to do is randomize the "jackpot_code" after each correct attemp.
[CLICK TO OPEN THE PHOTO OF DATABASE!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9u3G.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following code after successful insert command

if jackpot_code as int data type

```
 <?php 


   mysql_query("UPDATE `config` SET `jackpot_code`= ".rand(100,990)." WHERE `id`=1");

?>
```

if jackpot_code as varchar data type

```
 <?php 


   mysql_query("UPDATE `config` SET `jackpot_code`= '".rand(100,990)."' WHERE `id`=1");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
 $random =rand(100,999);
```

Comment: That is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have database full of codes and you want to get random one, use

```
SELECT * FROM config ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

Or if you want to generate new one, just add this before echoing "correct"

```
INSERT INTO config (jackpot_code) VALUES (rand())
```

and change select

```
SELECT * FROM config ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```